# Profile2 module field validation

Tags: users

I have created two profile types using profile2 module. Next added two fields to each of the profile types. Here one field of each profile type is set as REQUIRED. But when i select one field set and submit the form then the validation for other profile type is blocking me to submit the form.

Please help me to get the solution.

Comment: you have to add diffrent paths for diffrent profiles using a module profile 2 registration path if you are using it on registration page

Comment: i want two profiles within a single form.. selecting a role will display the corresponding profile type..

one form:
 2 profile type:
  teacher(field1*, field2) and student(field3*)
 when i select teacher and submit the form then it is displaying like "student is also required".

but i want that, student field validation must be off when submitting the form "teacher".

Comment: you can use js validation i.e clientside validation till now i can't find other answer for your question

Comment: Have you tried restricting the profiles per role (if that is what you are aiming for). This post has a patch: [Restrict profile2 type per roles](https://www.drupal.org/node/1593230)